# How to set log level for Firestore?

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

How to set log level for Firestore?

According to documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Firestore#setLogLevel), i should use setLogLevel method but i can't see method at Firestore client objects, like `FirestoreClient.getFirestore()`.

Comment: You're talking about FirestoreClient in the Java SDK?

Comment: Yes, that environment. I see now that the documentation i pointed is for JavaScript. Anyway, can't find were. It generates a lot of log with the default setting.

Answer (score 13):

For those who ended up here trying to change the log level for the JS Web SDK:

```
firebase.firestore.setLogLevel("debug");    // "debug" | "error" | "silent"
```

Notice the lack of () after firestore, as opposed to:

```
firebase.firestore().settings(/*...*/)
```

Comment: for v9 its:
import {setLogLevel} from "firebase/firestore";
setLogLevel("debug");
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#setloglevel

Answer (score 8):

Current versions for most environments documented [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/katowulf/0475fb7a5907ed757f687aab6ed15878).

**JavaScript**

```
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Firestore#setLogLevel
firebase.firestore.setLogLevel('debug');
```

**Node.js**

```
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Firestore#setLogLevel
firebase.firestore.setLogLevel('debug');
```

**Android**

```
// See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestore.html#setLoggingEnabled(boolean)
FirebaseFirestore.setLoggingEnabled(true);
```

**Swift**

```
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Firestore#enablelogging_
Firestore.enableLogging(true)
```

**Java Admin SDK**

Uses [SLF4J](https://www.slf4j.org/) (Java's built-in façade logger) as described in [Hiranya's blog post](https://medium.com/@hiranya911/logging-in-java-libraries-for-firebase-and-google-cloud-platform-f8742493b73f).

1) Add the `slf4j-simple` binding to the application classpath
  2) Set the `-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=debug` system property

**GCP environments**

```
# See https://medium.com/@hiranya911/logging-in-java-libraries-for-firebase-and-google-cloud-platform-f8742493b73f

.level=INFO
com.google.firebase.level=FINE
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format='%1$tY-%1$tm-%1$td %1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS %4$s %2$s %5$s%6$s%n'
```

Answer (score 1):

For **firebase-firestore:21.1.1** use this line:

```
FirebaseFirestore.setLoggingEnabled(true);
```

[Further Reference](https://gist.github.com/katowulf/0475fb7a5907ed757f687aab6ed15878)

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no logging functionality in the Java Server SDK for Firestore. Firestore supports logging in all the Mobile clients (Android, iOS and Web) as well as in the Node Server SDK.

Comment: when i run i get lots of lines like this `2018-02-08 00:16:46,098 DEBUG [grpc-default-worker-ELG-2-3] (io.netty.util.internal.logging.Slf4JLogger:86) - [id: 0x1f4aec1c, L:/192.168.1.70:50470 - R:firestore.googleapis.com/216.58.211.202:443] OUTBOUND SETTINGS: ack=false settings={ENABLE_PUSH=0, MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS=0, INITIAL_WINDOW_SIZE=1048576, MAX_HEADER_LIST_SIZE=8192}`

Comment: These are low-level gRPC logs. How did you manage to enable them? If this just happened, chances are you have a `logging.properties` file installed in your environment. You will have to find that, and update it accordingly.

Comment: I am not sure. I am using log4j logger. The io.netty.util is set to ´OFF´ at log4j.xml config file but i am still getting this, so i was trying to set it off in code.

Comment: Well the above entry is logged in the `DEBUG` level. So clearly something in you environment has enabled `DEBUG` level logs. Usually you don't get any logs when you run Firestore clients.

Comment: You can enable Java server-side logging by following [Hiranya's blog post](https://medium.com/@hiranya911/logging-in-java-libraries-for-firebase-and-google-cloud-platform-f8742493b73f)

Answer (score -2):

**For Angular-CLI**, Add this to your `app.module.ts` file:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
firebase.firestore.setLogLevel('debug');
```

[reference](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/190#issuecomment-371180738)