# How to disable firebase logs in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter

How to disable firebase logging or change the `loglevel` to min in flutter?

example of logs

```
[FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzaq@7862a17
D/FirebaseAuth( 6895): Notifying id token listeners about user ( Wr5ZryMbjqezcexb2a1KWt0W05C3 ).
W/Firestore( 6895): (21.3.0) [FirestoreCallCredentials]: Failed to get token: com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: getToken aborted due to token change.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to change the log level directly from your Flutter code.

But you can open the native runner app for Android, and change the log level there.

For example, for Firestore you'd call [setLoggingEnabled](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestore#setLoggingEnabled(boolean)), as also shown here: [How to set log level for Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48674134/how-to-set-log-level-for-firestore)

I'm actually not sure if the logging from Firebase Authentication can be disabled, but that should typically be a lot less (mostly on app startup, and then every hour when it refreshes its ID token).

Then when you rebuild the Android app, it will use the new settings, and you can continue writing the rest of your code in Flutter.