# Flutter Firestore floods logs when in offline mode

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Whenever the devices disconnects from the internet, Firebase starts logging a lot of messages ultimately flooding my logs. The app itself works as expected but is there a way of disabling these logs:

```
W/Firestore( 7811): (24.0.1) [WatchStream]: (3c37293) Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Unable to resolve host firestore.googleapis.com, cause=java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "firestore.googleapis.com": No address associated with hostname
W/Firestore( 7811):     at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.resolveAddresses(DnsNameResolver.java:223)
W/Firestore( 7811):     at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.doResolve(DnsNameResolver.java:282)
W/Firestore( 7811):     at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$Resolve.run(DnsNameResolver.java:318)
W/Firestore( 7811):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
W/Firestore( 7811):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
W/Firestore( 7811):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
W/Firestore( 7811): Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "firestore.googleapis.com": No address associated with hostname
W/Firestore( 7811):     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:156)
W/Firestore( 7811):     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:103)
W/Firestore( 7811):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1152)
W/Firestore( 7811):     at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$JdkAddressResolver.resolveAddress(DnsNameResolver.java:631)
W/Firestore( 7811):     at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.resolveAddresses(DnsNameResolver.java:219)
W/Firestore( 7811):     ... 5 more
W/Firestore( 7811): Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
```

Comment: It looks like you’d like to set the `loglevel` for the Firebase SDK to be less verbose. For Flutter specifically, have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62926725/) question already?

Comment: @Martin Have you found a solution for disabling logging?